# Running useFetch SSR (Server Side) but I see the XHR request client side

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

I'm using Nuxt3 in combination of Pinia. In pinia I have a function to authorize a user like:

```
async login (credentials: User) {      
  
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: 'testpass'
  }
};
  const { data: user }: any = await useFetch('https://endpoint.com/api/user/create-token', requestOptions)
  console.log(user.value.result.token)

  JwtService.saveToken(user.value.result.token)
},
```

Everything works fine as I get a token from the endpoint. The problem is; I want this fetch POST being fired at the server and not at the client. Currently I see the XHR in my client. How to fix this?

Application is running as SSR.